# Is pagination harmful?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, pagination

I am using PAGINATION mode in asp.net gridview i.e. pagesize 15

The gridview gets filled from datatable that gets filled from Database;

i.e.

```
Datatable dt= class.SelectTableDate();
```

in pageLoad event when page's called for the first time:

```
grdview.Datasource= dt;
grdview.DataBind();
```

now I am in argument with friend, he says that loading whole records from database would slow down the performance but what I am saying is that it only loads the data for the 1st page of gridview i.e. 15 records.

So what should we do ?

Update:

The question is "Is Pagination a good option or not ?"

Comment: Look at the query executed on the database - it will tell you how many rows are retrieved.

Comment: 566 rows to be exact

Comment: so how it can be prevented ?

Comment: Do not load whole grid, user is much slower that data loading. So server have more time to load data before pagination navigation. So your friend is right if we use the therm `good practice`

Comment: @Sebastian506563 the question is 'Is pagination a good option or not ?'

Comment: My advice would be: If you need paging, use it ... **but always filter first, to limit the number of rows returned!** Do not expect your users to page through more than 5 pages. Always imagine if you'd go through more than 5 pages in a google search result.

Comment: The attributes/fields to filter depend on your data. You could filter for the top 3 postal codes, etc. Your ~560 rows would be within the acceptable range to go unfiltered and Hugo's answer covers pretty much everything that can be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Time how long it takes to return 566 records versus the 15 you want to display per page.  If your queries are well written you'll find it's not a huge amount of time.

If you try to render the entire record set to the page you'll find there's quite the delay. That's simply down to rendering time, especially if your not setting the CSS attribute `table-layout: fixed;` to your grid.

Now the lets say you limit your query to 'properly' paginate 15 records at a time.  Every time your moving between pages your re-querying the database. And depending on your code structure you maybe creating new connections each time.  This would actually be worse than just getting down the entire 566 records in one hit.

What you can do is pull down the entire record set and cache that `DataTable` into a session variable. Naturally you need to be careful about managing your session data. But using this you get all data down in one initial hit then are free to paginate/sort/filter/whatever through it without any additional load to the database.